# Pre-evaulate object value when building an anonymous function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build up an array of handlers for a 3rd party control.  One of the required objects inside is a callback handler.  The problem is the allProvider(item) is called, the "theValue" variable no longer points to the same location - it always is set to the last value it was assigned to.  What I'd really like to do is evaluate the "theValue.name" immediately when building the array instead of later.  I'm open to about any solution at this point.  Thanks

```
var handlers = [];
for(var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
    var theValue = myArray[i];
    handlers.push({ 
        name: myArray.name,
        allProvider: function(item){
            return "All "+ theValue.name; //This always == myArray[myArray.length - 1]
        }
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a closure there - `theValue` is a reference to the parent scope's variable, and by the time that function is executed it is pointing to the last value it was assigned to.

[You need to break the closure](http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62). A common pattern is to use an IIFE.

```
allProvider: (function(theValue) {
               return function(item) {
                 return "All "+ theValue.name;
               }
             })(theValue)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.  You get the check for both being first and for the article - exactly what I needed.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Alex is correct, one possible way of solving this closure problem is to try this:

```
var handlers = [];

myArray.forEach(function (theValue) {
    handlers.push({ 
        name: myArray.name,
        allProvider: function(item){
            return "All "+ theValue.name;
        }
    });
});
```

Inside each anonymous function called within the `forEach` method, `theValue` will always point to what you expect.

**EDIT:** I wasn't thinking of something more efficient than what you had, just something that worked. `map` is definitely hitting two birds with one stone, so-to-speak, so you can also try this:

```
var handlers = myArray.map(function (theValue) {
    return { 
        name: myArray.name,
        allProvider: function(item){
            return "All "+ theValue.name;
        }
    };
});
```

Lastly, you can try this if you don't want something that could potentially break in older browsers that don't support `forEach` or `map`:

```
var handlers = [],
    i;

for(i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    (function (theValue) {
        handlers.push({ 
            name: myArray.name,
            allProvider: function(item){
                return "All "+ theValue.name;
            }
        });
    }(myArray[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is by the time the callback function is being called, the `for` loop is finished, So at the calling time `theValue` refers to last element in array.

I'll suggest you to use native array **map** function for your work like bellow:-

```
var handlers = myArray.map(function(theValue) {
    return {
        name: myArray.name,
        allProvider: function(item) {
            return "All " + theValue.name;
        }
    };
});
```

BTW **IE8 doesn't support the map function.**

If you want to support IE8 and lower What you can do bind each element in array to a function like bellow.

```
var getObject = function(arrName, valueName) {
    return {
        name: arrName,
        allProvider: function(item) {
            return "All " + valueName; 
        }
    }
}

var handlers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    var theValue = myArray[i];
    handlers.push(getObject(myArray.name,theValue.name));
}
```